Use sed command without staging the file yet using the changes to build docker image?
I have a Dockerfile, the image version needs to be updated as a part of the build and once the image is built needs to be pushed to ECR. But unfortunately the next step in GitHub Actions is a release job finds any files that are not committed before doing a release.
How can I use sed command but avoid making changes to the file, so git does not find staged files? Adding the Dockerfile to .gitignore file is not an option.
Error:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Aborting release: unstaged modified files

Dockerfile:
FROM image:tag

USER root

RUN mkdir -p dest

COPY src dest

bash script:
#! /bin/bash

export imageID=$(aws ecr describe-images --repository-name xxx \--query 'sort_by(imageDetails,& imagePushedAt)[-1].imageTags[0]' | tr -d '"')
echo $imageID
sed -i "s/tag/$imageID/g" Dockerfile
newImageID=$(echo ${imageID} | awk -F. -v OFS=. '{$NF += 1 ; print}')
echo $newImageID
docker build -t abc:$newImageID .
docker push abc:$newImageID

GitHub Actions workflow:
  - name: Copy files
        run: |
          bash ./copy_files_script.sh


Don't use sed. Use a build arg https://docs.docker.com/build/guide/build-args/ . The example given on the docs is your exact use case.

As commented, use Docker build args, it is ARG in the Dockerfile and allows templating/parameterization:
Dockerfile
ARG FROM_TAG=tag

FROM image:${FROM_TAG}

...

Now the Dockerfile does not need to be changed any longer and the parameter (FROM_TAG) build value can be passed to docker build.
That is the sed(1) call disappears from the build script:
Build Script
#! /bin/bash

export imageID=$(aws ecr describe-images --repository-name igloo \--query 'sort_by(imageDetails,& imagePushedAt)[-1].imageTags[0]' | tr -d '"')
newImageID=$(echo ${imageID} | awk -F. -v OFS=. '{$NF += 1 ; print}')
printf >&2 'image %s -> %s\n' "${imageID}" "${newImageID}"

docker build --build-arg="FROM_TAG=${imageID}" --tag "abc:${newImageID}" .
docker push "abc:${newImageID}"

If you for other files had a problem with changes as well, either mark them as unchanged (assume-unchanged in git), git clean/reset the tree or commit all modified and tracked files. That depends on the build workflow you'd like to achieve.
From the original error output, it looks like you want to have a new commit that captures the revision that is being build as not having it is the error the reminder of.
